# Html table thead gets cut off when printing

Tags: html, css, printing

I am using Firefox and trying to allow for a clean print of a table that is being displayed. Here is my code.

```
<style type="text/css">
table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #eee;
}

@media print {
@page { margin: 0; }
body { margin: 1.6cm; }
}

@media print {
a[href]:after {
content: none !important;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
<div>
<table class="header">
<thead>
<TR>
   <TH>x</TH>
</TR>
</thead>
<TR>
   <TD>x</TD>
</TR>
```

Many more rows and columns are in my code but I didnt include them. The `<thead>` works properly in Firefox but when I go to print it the row gets cut off slightly by the printer because it is to close to the top of the page. How can I add padding or something so that nothing gets cut off by the printer?

Here is some code I have already tried and didn't work

```
<style>
@media print {
tr.vendorListHeading {
background-color: #1a4567 !important;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}  

@media print {
.vendorListHeading th {
color: white !important;
    }
}

table { page-break-inside:auto }
tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
thead { display:table-header-group }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
</style>
```

Comment: you sure it's the html, and not just your printer chopping off because that bit its outside its printable area?

Comment: @MarcB I think that is the exact problem, so I want to push the <thead> down a bit so that It doesnt get stuck outside the printable area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add padding to the page using the page's margin or padding CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'd suggest just taking a screenshot and resizing the image in a document editor etc. and then printing that off.

It seems like unneccesary effort to start padding stuff etc. when the issue seems to be that your printer isn't printing right to the edge of the page.

Comment: I want to make it easy for my viewers to just print the page and have a paper copy of the live table.

Comment: Ah I see! Could you export the page as an image and use a blob to prompt the user to download it and print?

Comment: I mean I could but I am trying to just make it simple and easy without the hassle of downloading and dealing with all those files.